# Azure Stack HCI - How to move/migrate VM from one cluster to another cluster using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, hyper-v, windows-admin-center

How do I move or migrate a VM using PowerShell from a node in cluster01 to a node in cluster02? Thank you.

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75tc1.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4sfF.jpg)

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TQW0.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.